# Does SNMP have minimum time-out based on version

Tags: networking, storage, snmp

I know this is a very basic question but i was not aware since i'm new to SNMP stuff.So, is there any minimum timeout for SNMP based on version if so can you please specify the version and the timeout in seconds.

Comment: Manager side timeout? Agent side timeout? You do need to refer to user manuals and learn. Usually there is no version specific timeout setting on a device.

Answer (score 0):

As @LexLi mentioned, You need to be more specific about which timeouts are You asking. And, he is right, there is no dependency between version and timeout.

- snmpcmds like **snmpwalk\snmpget\snmpset...** have timeout
  *((**retries**+1) x **timeout_between_retries**)* seconds, which is *(5+1) x 1 = 6* seconds
  **by default**. Both parameters could be changed by either **command line**
  or **snmp.conf**.

  Example:

  ```
     snmpwalk -v2c -cpublic -r1 -t10 host OID
  ```

  *The maximum timeout here will be 20 seconds because we will send 2 queries with the timeout between them is 10 seconds.*
- Also there is **agentXTimeout and agentXRetries**, which are defining timeout for AgentX requests between masterAgent and subAgent. Values are the same: 5 times and 1 second ,respectively. Those values could be changed by the **command line** or in the **snmpd.conf**.